# From $b$ to $a$, and then $a$ to $b$, come find me!

Tags: riddle, cipher

> $\mathfrak{From\>}b\>\mathfrak{to\>}a,\mathfrak{and\>then\>}a\>\mathfrak{to\>}b,\mathfrak{come\>find\>me!}$
>   TWFyayB5b3VyIHNwb3QhIFdhbGsgZm9yd2FyZC4gCkFuZCBmb3J3YXJkLiBBbmQgZm9yd2FyZC4KQW5kIG5vdyB5b3UndmUgZm91bmQgeW91ciBzcG90IG9uIG1lLgpUcnkgYWdhaW4sIGdvaW5nIG92ZXIgdG8gbXkgb3RoZXIgc2lkZSwgYW5kIHdhbGsuCkhhdmUgeW91IGZvdW5kIHlvdXIgc3BvdD8gT2YgY291cnNlIHlvdSBoYXZlLgpXaGF0IGFtIEksIG5vdz8=
>   
> Even after this, can you find out what I am? For this is only the first step to infinity! But, after a while, you'll end up right where you started.

Hints:

> The first line is the title of the post.
> The title is a hint (in fact, is *essential* to solving the puzzle).
> It has two parts, the first being decoded the seemingly random arrangement of text. The second part is a riddle.
> The first part is programming-related
> The little blurb after the puzzle will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll take a shot at the second step. This is A E's solution to the first:

> Mark your spot! Walk forward. 
>  And forward. And forward. 
>  And now you've found your spot on me. 
>  Try again, going over to my other side, and walk. 
>  Have you found your spot? Of course you have. 
>  What am I, now?

---

Even after this, can you find out what I am? For this is only the first step to infinity! But, after a while, you'll end up right where you started.

> Möbius strip

After a while of walking, you'll end up right where you started.

> But once you found the spot, if you go the other way, you'll find the spot yet again.
>  If you start from the other side, you'll also end up at the spot again

Comment: Close, but not quite... By "going over to my other side," I mean that it is a 3-d shape.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Okay, I'll try the other thing that came to my mind

Comment: @ConorO'Brien There, how about now?

Comment: Perfect! Just the answer.

Answer (score 2):

First step:

Converting the ciphertext from

> Base64

gives plaintext:

> Mark your spot! Walk forward. 
>  And forward. And forward. 
>  And now you've found your spot on me. 
>  Try again, going over to my other side, and walk. 
>  Have you found your spot? Of course you have. 
>  What am I, now?

Why I did it this way:

> The '=' symbol at the end of the ciphertext is used as padding to make a base64 string the right length. So if you see an '=' at the end then it's always worth trying base64.

Perhaps the next step might be:

> Maybe the riddle is talking about travelling up and down the real number line, so a real number: 1 perhaps? That would fit with "first step to infinity".

Comment: Great job! I can't wait to see what you have for the second step...

Comment: Thank you @ConorO'Brien! I'm totally stumped on the 2nd step, need one of our riddle specialists for that. ;)